How am I able to find poles in this equation?
this following is  my code for KVL, KCL in circuit analysis.
I want to calculate $\frac{V_{D1}} {V_{in}}$ and $\frac{V_{s}} {V_{in}}$
eqn1 = -Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] Subscript[V, s  ] + (
    Subscript[V, D1] - Subscript[V, s])/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
    n1]] + Subscript[V, D1]/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
    p1]] + \[ImaginaryJ]*\[Omega]*Subscript[C, L1] Subscript[V, 
     D1] == 0;
eqn2 = (Subscript[V, in] - Subscript[V, s])/Subscript[R, s] == 
   Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] Subscript[V, s] - (
    Subscript[V, s] - Subscript[V, D1])/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, n1]];
Solve[eqn1 && eqn2, {Subscript[V, D1], Subscript[V, s]}]

TransferFunctionPoles[
 TransferFunctionModel[((-Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] - 1/
     Subscript[r, Subscript[o, n1]]) Subscript[V, 
   in])/(((-Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] - 1/Subscript[r, Subscript[
      o, n1]])/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
     n1]] + (I \[Omega] Subscript[C, L1] + 1/Subscript[r, Subscript[o,
         n1]] + 1/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
        p1]]) (-Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] + 1/Subscript[r, 
        Subscript[o, n1]] - 1/Subscript[R, s])) Subscript[R, 
   s]), \[Omega]]]

However, the poles doesn't looks correct in terms  of format. I am using Mathematica 12.0

I suppose you know that subscripts are not necessarily the problem (see point 3). I don't use them, and I tend to avoid questions such as this that use them; so I don't have a well-developed sense of when they are a problem. I believe in this case, the use of Subscript[] might mean that there are twice as many parameters than a human would think. (E.g Subscript[a, b] depends on both a and b.) But maybe it doesn't matter.

Both transfer functions have the same denominator thus,
eqn1 = -Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] Subscript[V, s  ] + (
    Subscript[V, D1] - Subscript[V, s])/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
    n1]] + Subscript[V, D1]/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
    p1]] + \[ImaginaryJ]*\[Omega]*Subscript[C, L1] Subscript[V, 
     D1] == 0;
eqn2 = (Subscript[V, in] - Subscript[V, s])/Subscript[R, s] == 
   Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] Subscript[V, s] - (
   Subscript[V, s] - Subscript[V, D1])/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, n1]];

sol = Solve[eqn1 && eqn2, {Subscript[V, D1], Subscript[V, s]}][[1]]

transf = {Subscript[V, D1]/Subscript[V, in], Subscript[V, s]/Subscript[V, in]} /. sol // Simplify
Solve[Denominator[transf[[1]]] == 0, \[Omega]] // Simplify


Assume $g_{m_{n1}} r_{o_{n1}} \gg 1$ and $g_{m_{p1}} r_{o_{p1}} \gg 1$ is there a way to simplify it further
